# What does "(obsolete)" mean in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center

I sometimes see software in Ubuntu Software Center with "(obsolete)" at the end of the title. What does this mean? Are there any risks? Is there a simple way to get to a non-obsolete version?

For example, some git and rails tutorials online direct you to install git-core. USC says that git-core is obsolete. I guess I should just install git instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will usually mean that the package has been renamed, and the one you are looking at is the old name, but kept available for a while to ensure that upgrades work as expected.

In the case of git the package was renamed from `git-core` to `git`, so you are right about wanting to install `git`.

However, `git-core` depends on git, so installing either will get you the software you want.

Answer (score 0):

Softwares are written as to work with a given specific version of the Ubuntu, Obsolete Software may either mean that the software in the question may be Old for the current version of OS or a Newer version of the Software is available, hope i cleared your doubt.

Comment: Though there is no potential harm in installing Obsolete softwares it is not recommended as it may underperform